# Why doesn't my search function work?

Tags: python, django

I'm currently trying to implement a search functionality to my Django app. Everything works perfectly fine, until the actual search query is handled. Say, I search for "hallo". Django would the return the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'title' into field. Choices are: adresse, arbejde, beskrivelse, email, foerste_session, fulde_navn, id, profilbillede, relateret_til_andre_klienter, tidligere_klient, vurder_sidste_session
```

There seems to be some sort of conflict between my form (I am using a ModelForm) and my search function. How do I go about solving my problem?

Here is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Client

class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = (
            'fulde_navn',
            'adresse',
            'email',
            'tidligere_klient',
            'foerste_session',
            'beskrivelse',
            'arbejde',
            'relateret_til_andre_klienter',
            'vurder_sidste_session',
            'profilbillede'
        )
```

And here is my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

import os
import uuid

YESNO_CHOICES = (
    (0, 'Ja'),
    (1, 'Nej')
    )


SESSION_CHOICES = (
    (0, '1'),
    (1, '2'),
    (2, '3'),
    (3, '4'),
    (4, '5'),
    )

def upload_to_location(instance, filename):
    blocks = filename.split('.')
    ext = blocks[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
    instance.title = blocks[0]
    return os.path.join('uploads/', filename)
# Create your models here.

class Client(models.Model):
    fulde_navn = models.CharField('Navn', max_length=75)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    tidligere_klient = models.IntegerField(choices=YESNO_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    foerste_session = models.DateField('Dato for 1. session', null=True, blank=True)
    beskrivelse = models.TextField('Noter', null=True, blank=True)
    arbejde = models.CharField('Arbejde', max_length=200)
    relateret_til_andre_klienter = models.IntegerField(choices=YESNO_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    vurder_sidste_session = models.IntegerField(choices=SESSION_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    profilbillede = models.ImageField('Profilbillede',
                                upload_to='profile_pics/%Y-%m-%d/',
                                null=True,
                                blank=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fulde_navn

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(viewname="client_detail", args=[self.id])
```

And finally my views.py where my search function is located:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView
from . import models
from .forms import ClientForm
# Create your views here.

class ClientsListView(ListView):
    model = models.Client
    template_name = 'clients/list.html'
    paginate_by = 20


class SearchListView(ClientsListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        incoming_query_string = self.request.GET.get('query', '')
        return models.Client.objects.filter(title__icontains=incoming_query_string)


class ClientsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = models.Client
    template_name = 'clients/detail.html'


def client_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClientForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            client = form.save()
            client.save()
            return redirect('client_detail', pk=client.pk)
    else:
        form = ClientForm()

    return render(request, 'clients/form.html', {'form': form})

def client_edit(request, pk):
    client = get_object_or_404(models.Client, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ClientForm(request.POST, instance=client)
        if form.is_valid():
            client = form.save()
            client.save()
            return redirect('client_detail', pk=client.pk)
    else:
        form = ClientForm(instance=client)
    return render(request, 'clients/form.html', {'form': form})


class ClientsUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = models.Client
    template_name = 'clients/form.html'
```

How do I solve this problem? I want to make it so my user is able to search for clients in my list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
return models.Client.objects.filter(title__icontains=incoming_query_string)
```

You are trying to check if the field `title`contains the `incoming_query_string`. However, your `ClientForm` doesn't have such field.

You should use one of the fields you listed there or add `title` as a field.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `ClientForm`, it's the `Client` model that doesn't have `title` field. Also there's another place in `upload_to_location` function that might have problem: `instance.title = blocks[0]`.

Comment: Srsly, thx Amaury!! Worked like a charm. I am pretty new to Python/Django development